# Font not loading in Epub

Tags: fonts

I have this folder structure:

```
./Fonts/chimod.otf
./Styles/style.css
./Text/main.xhtml
content.opf
toc.ncx
```

Here is the content.opf:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<package xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" unique-identifier="bookid" version="2.0" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
  <metadata xmlns:opf="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <!-- ISBN -->
    <dc:identifier id="bookid" opf:scheme="ISBN">urn:isbn:971-1-911701-61-8</dc:identifier>
    <dc:title>Title</dc:title>
    <dc:rights>Copyright © 2020 Foo. All rights reserved.</dc:rights>

    <!-- BISAC Subject Headings List: http://bisg.org/?page=BISACFaQ -->
    <dc:subject>Religion / Philosophy / Nature</dc:subject>

    <!-- https://www.loc.gov/marc/relators/relacode.html -->
    <dc:creator opf:file-as="Foo" opf:role="bkd">Foo</dc:creator>

    <dc:publisher>Foo</dc:publisher>
    <dc:date opf:event="publication">2020-07-14</dc:date>

    <!-- Language code: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-2_codes -->
    <dc:language>en</dc:language>

    <meta name="cover" content="[COVER_NAME].jpg" />

    <!-- UUID generator: http://www.famkruithof.net/uuid/uuidgen -->
    <dc:identifier opf:scheme="UUID">urn:uuid:7d6649a0-c5cb-1aea-8b6e-08a020ac9a66</dc:identifier>
  </metadata>
  <manifest>
    <item id="css-fonts" href="Styles/style.css" media-type="text/css" />
    <item href="Text/main.xhtml" id="main" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
    <item href="Fonts/chimod.otf" id="chimod.otf" media-type="application/opentype" />
    <item href="toc.ncx" id="ncx" media-type="application/x-dtbncx+xml" />
  </manifest>
  <spine toc="ncx">
    <itemref idref="main" />
  </spine>
  <guide>
    <reference href="Text/main.xhtml" type="text" />
  </guide>
</package>
```

Here is the style:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Zh;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url(../Fonts/chimod.otf) format('otf');
}

@page {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  size: 178mm 254mm;
  color: #333;
}

body {
  font-family: Zh;
  color: #333;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Styles/style.css"/>
  </head>
  <body><span class="f-zh q">二</span></body></html>
```

Why isn't the font loading and displaying when I open the Epub?

I am compiling with this: https://github.com/javierarce/epub-boilerplate. I customized that to get it working. Getting no errors about resources not found. The font is the Chinese google noto font.

Comment: Have you validated the epub with epubcheck? What are the results? IIRC, when you use embedded fonts, it throws up some INFO/WARNINGS, but the file still validates. I assume you have checked your file paths already to make sure that is correct.

Comment: I haven't used an otf font file, but what you have looks basically correct. (I use TTF instead).  You should try another font just to see what happens... The problem may lie with the reading system you use to test render or the font itself, so it's important to rule these out... What you have looks correct so far.

Comment: I think what you did looks correct already, but you might find this reference to be useful https://github.com/JayPanoz/Soma/wiki/How-to-embed-fonts

Comment: I used Mac Books to render if that matters.

Comment: Because you did not give me the output of epubcheck, there is no way to answer the question.  My guess is that you used a wrong file path.